# Exercise Analysis.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Define $\phi(s)=\int_\Omega{e^{-sf}}d\nu$ where $\nu$ is a finite measure, $s\geq0 $ and $f$ is a non-negative measurable function . Consider also that $V$ is a real function such that

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{V (x)}\rightarrow \infty \,\,\,\,\, \textrm{.}$$

Show that for $t>0$ and $x$ sufficiently large and $\epsilon >0$

$$\phi(te^{-V(x)})-1 \leq (1- \epsilon)\ln\phi(te^{-V(x)}) \,\,\,\,\,\textrm{ .}$$

My idea: I started with

If $x$ is sufficiently large, for all $\epsilon>0 $ we have $e^{-V(x)}\leq \epsilon$. But I can not use any kind of growth of function to get the inequality. Help?

Comment: Is this from a textbook?

Comment: Yes, Branching Random Walk by Zhan Shi.

Comment: is the $\epsilon$ supposed to be arbitrarily small (in the equation that you have to show)? please specify the quantors!

Comment: No, any $\epsilon > 0$. I edited the post, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false.

If we choose $f=0, \nu(\Omega)=2$ we have $\phi(s)=2$ for all $s$.
Then by using $\epsilon=1$ the inequality becomes
$$ 1 \leq 0$$
which is impossible

Comment: Ok. To be precise, I'm interested in probability space. If $\epsilon$ is small  sufficiently is this statement true?